# Python Exception cought but stack trace printed anyways

Tags: python-3.x, exception

I'm trying to understand why does the stack trace gets printed event
though the exception is caught. Here is the example off different approaches:

Approach 1

```
import soco
try:
    ... code that can result with the exception...
except soco.exceptions.SoCoUPnPException as e:
    logger.warning("Exception caught. Not expecting trace")
```

Approach 2

```
from soco.exceptions import SoCoUPnPException
try:
    ... code that can result with the exception...
except SoCoUPnPException as e:
    logger.warning("Exception caught. Not expecting trace")
```

Approach 3

```
try:
    ... code that can result with the exception...
except Exception as e:
    logger.warning("Exception caught. Not expecting trace")
```

They all results in the same error:

```
ERROR [soco.services:410] UPnP Error 701 received: Transition not available from 10.10.10.114
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/soco/services.py", line 408, in send_command
    self.handle_upnp_error(response.text)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/soco/services.py", line 469, in handle_upnp_error
    error_xml=xml_error
soco.exceptions.SoCoUPnPException: UPnP Error 701 received: Transition not available from 10.10.10.114
WARNING [senic_hub.nuimo_app.components.sonos:180] Exception caught. Not expecting trace
```

I would expect just the `logger.warning("Exception caught. Not expecting trace")` part to be printed instead the whole trace.

**Update**

Removed the `try/catch` statement in which case the `soco.exceptions.SoCoUPnPException` gets raised twice.

Exception code: https://github.com/SoCo/SoCo/blob/release-0.14/soco/exceptions.py#L22

What am I missing here?

Comment: only `except:` ?

Comment: @Mika72 It seems as though the exception is being caught successfully in all three cases given that `Exception caught. Not expecting trace` does get printed.
Perhaps it's a library issue and not the way the exception is handled in the code...

Answer (score 0):

The exception is being caught correctly. Check the documentation for the [Logger](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.html) class. Using it the way you have results in the exception information being printed by default (as documented in the [debug](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug) section; the `info`, `warning`, etc. levels use the same behavior as well).

There are three keyword arguments (Python 3) that can be used to adjust this behavior:

- `exc_info` - causes exception information to be added to the logging message
- `stack_info` - causes stack information to be added to the logging message **Python 3 only**
- `extra` - accepts a dictionary to populate the `__dict__` of the `LogRecord` used for the logging event.

To suppress the stack and exception info, try the following:

```
import logging
import soco

try:
    ... code that can create exception ...
except soco.exceptions.SoCoUPnPException as e:
    logger.warning("Exception caught. Not expecting trace", exc_info=False, stack_info=False)    # Remove the 'stack_info=False' for Python 2
```

Comment: Not the case, but thanks. Also `stack_info` does default to `False`. Don't really know what to make of the default value from `If exc_info does not evaluate as false` (the docs ref you posted)

Comment: @TheMeaningfulEngineer Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @TheMeaningfulEngineer what isn't the case? Did you set `exc_info` to `False`? That would cause it to evaluate to false. It means you need to pass it a value or an expression which results in a `False` value.

Comment: Sorry, tested the suggestion you made. That wasn't the case that solves it. It seems to default to `False` in python 3 then.

Comment: @TheMeaningfulEngineer what is the print out if you just use the `print` function, instead of the `logger.warning`?

Comment: It's the same. Would conclude that it isn't a logger problem. Having a gut feeling it could be something with the library implementation and not a python generic problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170685/discussion-between-twreever-and-themeaningfulengineer).